# How to synchronize two databases for a wordpress project?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, synchronization

i'm working on a wordpress project with another dev, we need to synchronize our databases while pushing in gitlab, is there any other plugin than Database Sync or something else to solve the problem ?

Comment: is command line not an option to sync the databases?

Comment: maybe look into these plugins https://www.sitepoint.com/synchronize-wordpress-live-development-databases/

Answer (score 0):

The best option is MySQL Replication. It{s really easy to set up and can permit you to replicate every single change on the structure and/or data between your databases.

For that kind of project, the best option is setting up a master-master replication topology.

You can follow any of these links with detailed examples:

https://udhyantimilsina.com/2012/10/25/master-to-master-replication-of-mysql-server-in-windows-server-2008/

https://www.ryadel.com/en/mysql-master-master-replication-setup-in-5-easy-steps/